# staging server with rbenv passenger and rails

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, rbenv

I have a staging server and I'd like to make it run both ruby1.8.7/Rails2 and ruby1.9.3/Rails3 application. 
The server was successfully set up with nginix rbenv ruby 1.8.7 passenger and rails 2. Now I want to add the rails3 application along with ruby1.9.3 but I wonder if I really can do that as I had to tell nginix which particular passenger to use in its nginx.conf. This setting

```
passenger_root /home/rails_user/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.24;
passenger_ruby /home/rails_user/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby;
```

or this one:

```
#passenger_root /home/rails_user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.24;
#passenger_ruby /home/rails_user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby;
```

After adding ruby 1.9 and my rails3 I notice that if I use the first one, my old 1.8 app keep running but not the new one. The opposite happened if I use the latter configuration. 
At this point it looks to me as it is not possible to get both working or at least not in this way. Am I right?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the moment I managed to move forward with:

```
passenger_root /home/rails_user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.24;
passenger_ruby /home/rails_user/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

but I'm not sure it is the right/best solution. Any opinion will be well-accepted thanks

Comment: Have you come across a different answer since then? It looks like 1) installing into, say, `/opt`, 2) symlinking it into `/usr/local/bin` and 3) setting `rbenv_root=/opt/rbenv` will be an effective solution. Homebrew does it in a similar way on Mac: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/rbenv.rb