# multiple rubies under nginx with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rbenv

I have a staging server and I'd like to make it run both ruby1.8.7/Rails2 and ruby2.1.5/Rails3 application. Previously I had it working someway [by using the passenger gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078951/staging-server-with-rbenv-passenger-and-rails) but now I had to reinstall nginx/1.6.2 and Passenger/5.0.6 which I did this time by the [official way](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu).

Now only *ibra* (ruby2.1.5/Rails3) responds correctly while the other one (ruby1.8.7/Rails2) returns the following 3 errors:

```
2015/04/20 18:37:54 [error] 24843#0: *11 directory index of "/home/rails_user/rails_deploy/valborbera/current/public/" is forbidden, client: 172.21.42.35, server: vipp, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "172.21.42.6"
```

the following is my */etc/nginx/nginx.conf*

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # Phusion Passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##

        passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
        passenger_ruby /home/rails_user/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rails_apps;
}
```

While the following is my */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rails_apps*:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name vipp;
    root /home/rails_user/rails_deploy/valborbera/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env staging;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
}
server {
    listen 82;
    server_name ibra;
    root /home/rails_user/rails_deploy/ibra/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env staging;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
}
```

if I add `autoindex on;` I can see the files which makes forbidden error even more obscure to me..

any idea?

Comment: reinstalling passenger (version 4.0.59) and nginx by the gem *solves* the problem. But of course I would have used passenger 5 and I still wonder why it didn't work..

Comment: Try to set ruby version explicitly in your server config (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_application_loading_options)